# Cannot connect to external 192.168 address

Tags: networking, vpn, router, gateway

I am connected via VPN to another network which uses IP addresses in the range 192.168.x.x. I have changed my home network to not use that network (I use 10.10.x.x). However, I cannot seem to access anything on a 192.168.0.0 subnet even though I have changed my internal network. Is there anything that would be preventing this from connecting (I have a linksys wrt160n).

Comment: I would suggest contacting the administrator responsible for the destination VPN. The information you have provided is insufficient for making a determination and home networking is off-topic for ServerFault.

Comment: Yes, perhaps the VPN isn't working?

Comment: I can connect to other things over the VPN, just not the 192.168 subnet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that you have a route to that subnet.  Additionally, ensure that the subnet at the other end has a route to you.

One typical way this is done is to have the VPN virtual interface assign an IP address in the destination subnet.  If the intention is to link both subnets together, the VPN will integrate with the gateway routers on each end and there will be a route between the two subnets over the VPN.

Either way, do a traceroute and see where the breakdown is.  Ensure the traffic is following the right path (eg. toward and over the VPN), and can get back.  For instance, if your computer gets an address on the remote subnet from the VPN client, ensure that the packets are not going out through your local gateway (though the VPN traffic itself should obviously go that way; it is the encapsulated traffic that should not).

Comment: Thanks, I'll do some investigation and see what happens.